# RWMutex in conditional variable

Tags: go, mutex

Why `RWMutex` in conditional variable doesn't have `RLock` and `RUnLock` methods?

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    cond := &sync.Cond{L: &sync.RWMutex{}}
    cond.L.RLock()
    cond.L.RUnlock()
}
```

I got an error:

```
cond.L.RLock undefined (type sync.Locker has no field or method RLock)
cond.L.RUnlock undefined (type sync.Locker has no field or method RUnlock)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LdGYlrQQx86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `sync.Cond` only makes use of the methods required by a [sync.Locker](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Locker): `Lock` and `Unlock`. The minimal [interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces) needed by `Cond` is therefore just those two methods.

You can still use your `RWMutex` directly (as opposed to going through `Cond`), and `Cond` will still work.

```
func main() {
    myMutex := &sync.RWMutex{}
    cond := sync.NewCond(myMutex)
    // Use the RW mutex directly.
    myMutex.RLock()
    myMutex.RUnlock()
    // Use the mutex through cond. Lock and Unlock only.
    cond.L.Lock()
    cond.L.Unlock()
}
```

Or you can use it through `Cond.L` after making sure it is of the expected type:

```
func main() {
    cond := &sync.Cond{L: &sync.RWMutex{}}
    // Typecheck cond.L.
    myRWMutex, ok := cond.L.(*sync.RWMutex)
    if !ok {
        panic("AHHHH!!!")
    }
    myRWMutex.RLock()
    myRWMutex.RUnlock()
}
```

(you can skip the type check and just say `cond.L.(*sync.RWMutex)` but if it isn't a `sync.RWMutex`, your program will panic)